# Jenkins Pipeline Maven Artifactory Plugin Cannot Resolve Artifact From Central Maven Repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory, jenkins-pipeline

When using a Jenkins Freestyle Project I am able to successfully run a build with Maven using the "Maven3-Artifactory Integration."

When trying to use this feature in pipeline I run into issues with resolving artifacts from the central maven repository. I am under the impression that when Jenkins cannot find an artifact in artifactory it should fall back to the central maven repository,https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, to look for the artifact. Is this not the case?

```
def server = Artifactory.server SERVER_ID
def rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()
rtMaven.resolver server: server, releaseRepo: 'my-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'my-snapshot-local'
rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: 'my-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'my-snapshot-local'
rtMaven.deployer.artifactDeploymentPatterns.addInclude("").addExclude("")
rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = false
rtMaven.tool = MAVEN_TOOL
def buildInfo = rtMaven.run pom: POM_FILE, goals: GOALS
server.publishBuildInfo buildInfo
```

From the console output it seems like Jenkins is forcing the build to only resolve artifacts from Artifactory and nowhere else, even though it sees the central repo.

```
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener - [buildinfo] Resolved artifact: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5:build from: central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2, releases) Context is: plugin
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ResolutionHelper - [buildinfo] Properties file '/tmp/buildInfo6034012728922541318.properties' retrieved from 'System.getProperty(buildInfoConfig.propertiesFile)'
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseResolversHelper - [buildinfo] Enforcing snapshot repository for resolution: mysnapshotartifactoryURL
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseResolversHelper - [buildinfo] Enforcing repository authentication: username=myusername, password=*** for snapshot resolution repository
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseResolversHelper - [buildinfo] Enforcing release repository for resolution: myreleaseartifactoryURL
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseResolversHelper - [buildinfo] Enforcing repository authentication: username=myusername, password=*** for release resolution repository
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseArtifactResolver - Verifying availability of /home/myusername/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-plugins/22/maven-plugins-22.pom from [artifactory-release (myreleaseartifactoryURL, releases), artifactory-snapshot (mysnapshotartifactoryURL, snapshots)]
[main] DEBUG org.jfrog.build.extractor.maven.resolver.ArtifactoryEclipseRepositoryListener - [buildinfo] Could not resolve artifact: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:22:build
[main] ERROR org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli - Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:pom:22 in artifactory-release (myreleaseartifactoryURL)-> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
```

Comment: Did you try removing the "rtMaven.resolver" method?

Comment: Removing the call to `rtMaven.resolver` made it work for me, thanks. 
This should at least be an alternative answer to the question, as I cannot find any reference in the documentation that setting a resolver will have the Maven build silently ignore any repositories defined in the pom. Maybe it is obvious, but very confusing to a newbie.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem some time ago. I don't know if it applies for you. The flow is what I remember from artifactory:

1. check on  `libs-release-local`, which we were using for local builds. this has **Virtual Repository Associations** with **libs-release**
2. **libs-release** is a virtual repo. And **Included Repositories** under libs-release are  **libs-release-local** AND **maven-central-custom**
3. Resolution and upload of artifacts is done to/from **libs-release-local**. Incase the requred artifact is not available, maven is following *libs-release-local* --> *libs-release* --> *maven-central-custom*

And the following is how we use it inside our jenkinsfile:

```
// Obtain an Artifactory server instance, defined in Jenkins --> Manage:
def server = Artifactory.server 'localArtifactory'
def rtMaven
def buildInfo

// Artifactory Maven Build instance
rtMaven = Artifactory.newMavenBuild()


rtMaven.tool = 'localMaven'

//where the Maven build should download its dependencies from
rtMaven.resolver server: server, releaseRepo: 'libs-release' , snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot'

//define where our build artifacts should be deployed to. we define the Artifactory server and repositories on the 'rtMaven' instance
rtMaven.deployer server: server, releaseRepo: 'libs-release-local', snapshotRepo: 'libs-snapshot-local'


//disable pushing to artifactory, true if requered
rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = false

//By default, all the build artifacts are deployed to Artifactory. So, let's make filter and deployArtifacts=true
rtMaven.deployer.artifactDeploymentPatterns.addInclude("*-common-*")

rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean package'
rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts buildInfo
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like your code above is all declarations. Have you got an example of how that actually invoked in Jenkins processing method?

Comment: @NestorMilyaev this is all you need. Of course, it is better to add different stages for different operations. `rtMaven.run pom: 'pom.xml', goals: 'clean package'` does all you need. Note that you can change the goal, I would say `install`.  You can have `rtMaven.deployer.deployArtifacts = false` to disable pushing to artifactory.