# Maven only resolving artifacts from Artifactory or central, not both

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory

I'm trying to set up a maven build in Jenkins (running in Docker) and i've set it to resolve artifacts from a Artifactory server with the [Artifactory plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin). However, i can't manage to get it to resolve artifacts through both Artifactory and the central repository. When i check the 'Resolve artifacts from Artifactory' option in my build environment settings it will fail to resolve things like the maven-resources-plugin since it will look for it in Artifactory:

```
Could not find artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-plugins:
```

When running maven with debug options i get this log entry:

```
[DEBUG] Enforcing Artifactory artifact resolver
```

If i uncheck the option then it will resolve correctly but then it obviously won't resolve the artifacts needed from Artifactory.

[Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43745880/jenkins-pipeline-maven-artifactory-plugin-cannot-resolve-artifact-from-central-m?rq=1)

Comment: Please provide your pom

Comment: Also, add the relevant log parts from Artifactory.